# How to parse this xml using PHP 4.4.8?

Tags: php, xml

usually i have no problems parsing xml in PHP 5 by using Xml to array class.
but now, i have a server with PHP 4.4.8 , and i really don't know how to parse it using built-in functions.

the xml is like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?pageview_candidate?>
 <SearchResponse Version="2.2">
  <web:Web>
   <web:Results>

     <web:WebResult>
       <web:Title>Apple Ipad</web:Title>
       <web:Description>The best way to experience the web</web:Description>
       <web:Url>http://www.apple.com/ipad/</web:Url>
     </web:WebResult>

     <web:WebResult>
       <web:Title>Apple Tablet Concept: the iPad Touch</web:Title>
       <web:Description>This can all be made better!</web:Description>
       <web:Url>http://factoryjoe.com/blog/148548/</web:Url>
     </web:WebResult>

   </web:Results>
  </web:Web>
 </SearchResponse>
```

I want to `echo` every search item, the title & description & url.

Note: the important is that the code should work in PHP Version 4.4.8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [xml_parser*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php) functions should still work in PHP4:-

```
$xml = "...."
$parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($parser);
```

Check out the manual for more in depth examples.

Edit:- Found a duplicate here: [What to use for XML parsing / reading in PHP4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132233/what-to-use-for-xml-parsing-reading-in-php4)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [xslt_process](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xslt-process.php) and process it using an XSLT stylesheet. Take a look at some of the examples on that page. If you're unfamiliar with XSLT, [here's a simple example](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xslttutorial.php) with similar XML markup to yours.