# xml parsing in php4

Tags: php, xml, parsing, php4

I know that this might be way too much to ask, but I have been reading about xml parsing and I just do not understand it! I did not realize that my client had PHP 4 until I was done programming (a lesson well learned), but I need this to work in php4:

```
$post_string= 'type=xml&cid=55505&minorRev=14&apiKey=4sr8d8bsn75tpcuja6ypx5g3&locale='.$userLocale.'&currencyCode='.$userCurr.'&customerIpAddress='.$userIp.'&customerUserAgent='.$userAgent.'&xml=<HotelListRequest><destinationId>7EEF0188-E4DC-4B45-B4A7-57E3DF950E1F</destinationId><supplierCacheTolerance>MED_ENHANCED</supplierCacheTolerance><numberOfResults>200</numberOfResults></HotelListRequest>';
//Relative path to the file with $_POST parsing
$path = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list"; 
$ch = curl_init($path); 
$fp = fopen('xml/data.xml','w');
//Send the data to the file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$val = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);//Close curl session
fclose($fp); //Close file overwrite
$data = simplexml_load_file('xml/data.xml');
```

I am simply stumped. I have only ever used this format to read an xml document. Can anyone out there transform this to work on php4?? Again I know that this is a lot to ask, but any help would be so greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just Curious .. Why PHP 4 ???

Comment: Your client should really, really migrate to PHP 5. PHP 4 is no longer being maintained, not even with security updates. If it's with a hosting company, and they refuse to update, leave. (There are some cases where PHP 4 is needed because of old software but unless there's a totally pressing reason, using PHP 4 is a no-go today.)

Comment: Seriously? PHP4? I would be upset to have to work with 5.2 these days. I suggest you point your client toward this page: http://php.net/releases/index.php. PHP4 is obsolete and dangerously insecure. But more importantly, given how long it's been since it was discontinued, the OS running PHP4 is also likely to be dangerously insecure. Your client is in serious risk of being hacked just by having this kind of system online. Your problem is that they probably have their heads in the sand: by taking on the project, if they are hacked, there's a good chance you'll get the blame. My advice: Run away

Comment: I agree completely.. but he does not want to change and his hosting company will not migrate. So I have no options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to use for XML parsing / reading in PHP4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132233/what-to-use-for-xml-parsing-reading-in-php4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a note to your client that PHP 4 has not had any support **at all** since [August 8<sup>th</sup>, 2008](http://www.php.net/archive/2007.php)!

That said, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132233/what-to-use-for-xml-parsing-reading-in-php4) question which already address your problem.

(from referenced answer)

```
$xml = ...; // Get your XML data
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();

// _start_element and _end_element are two functions that determine what
// to do when opening and closing tags are found
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "_start_element", "_end_element");

// How to handle each char (stripping whitespace if needs be, etc
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "_character_data");  

xml_parse($xml_parser, $xml);
```

If your client *really* want to stick with unsupported PHP versions (or can't migrate to PHP 5), it is something that *he* should assume the cost for; maintaining legacy code usually requires more efforts.

Comment: The acceptance shows that this is duplicate material, it's perhaps well worth to delete then.